# Function ord works only sometimes but sometimes not

Tags: cobol

I am trying to programm some kind of [Caesar Cipher](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher#COBOL) in Cobol. But somehow I get the following compile error:

> Numeric function "INTEGER FUNCTION ORD" was not allowed in this context.

This error gets fired here (both lines)

```
 000048                  MOVE FUNCTION ORD("A") TO a
 000049                  display function ord("A")
```

But *NOT* here

```
 000054                MOVE FUNCTION CHAR(FUNCTION MOD(
 000055                    FUNCTION ORD(outstring (i:1))
 000056                        - a + offset, 26) + a)
 000057                TO outstring (i:1)
```

`i` is the position of the `outstring` we are looking at. `a` is the value of `"a"` or of `"A"` needed to make sure we stay in the 26 letters, defined as

```
 000018            03 a    pic S9(3).
```

Where is the difference? Why does the second work and the first not?

Comment: Just to say: I was not able to solve the problem since we were not using ascii but an other where a to z are not in order but with gaps..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example works and the first doesn't because you're allowed to have numeric expressions as function arguments but you can't have numeric expressions as the subject of a `MOVE` statement. In your case, your compiler ([IBM?](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.ilecbl.doc/evflnc40844.htm)) considers a numeric intrinsic function call to be a numeric expression. So you need to replace the `MOVE` with `COMPUTE` and change the function call in the `DISPLAY` to `a`.

```
000048                  COMPUTE a = FUNCTION ORD("A")
000049                  DISPLAY a
```